# Flutter how to change app name when app hover

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

How to change app name that hovering above the app?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's changed from the `MaterialApp`, in the `title` property:

```
MaterialApp(
 title: "your app title",
 /*...*/
 ),
```